# Create labels dynamically ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created some labels dynamically usgin this code

```
Label new_lbl = new Label();
new_lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
new_lbl.ID = "lab" + i;
new_lbl.Text = "Vous avez atteint le seuil minimal des " + con.dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j - 2].ToString() + " " + con.dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j - 1].ToString();
Panel1.Controls.Add(new_lbl);
```

But I get them next to each other. How can I get them vertically aligned ???

I appreciate your help.

Comment: you should add a br tag.

Comment: I know but where ? Can you please help ^_^

Comment: Stop thinking .NET and start thinking html, you've put labels on the screen. You can use Divs, BRs, CSS or even tables!

Comment: you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below menioend code

```
new_lbl.Text = "Vous avez atteint le seuil minimal des " + con.dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j - 2].ToString() + " <br/>" + con.dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j - 1].ToString();
```

Comment: I gotta wait for 8 more minutes (y)
Thank you